# syntax error at or near "I" while trying to insert rows in postgresql via python script

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

Trying to insert a query into a postgres table via python code.

Code line:

```
query = f"INSERT INTO Phone (data, result, reason) VALUES ('{json.dumps(data)}', {val}, '{json.dumps(reason)}') RETURNING id;"
```

here, `data` and `reason` are columns of type `json` and `result` is a `bool`column.

Query on printing the variable:

```
INSERT INTO Phone (data, result, reason) VALUES ('{'ICl': False, 'Poster': True, 'Lock': True, 'Model': 'ABC'}', True, '{}') RETURNING id;
```

Error:

```
syntax error at or near "I"
LINE 1: I
        ^
```

The same query on copy pasting into Table plus directly gives me no error and the row gets inserted.

Where is the error? Can't seem to understand why the query is giving me such error that too only in Python code. Please help.

Comment: Which database module are you using? psycopg2?

Comment: yes. psycopg2 module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let `psycopg2` handle the quoting for you.
Please try this:

```
query = """INSERT INTO Phone (data, result, reason) 
               VALUES (%s,%s,%s) RETURNING id;"""

cursor.execute(query, (json.dumps(data), val, json.dumps(reason),))
```

Comment: This worked for me. Guess I need to eliminate the use of f-strings when it comes to inserting data into db. 
Thanks for that.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you cannot do the formatting yourself. If, on the other hand, you want to do string formatting for table and/or column names you'll need f-strings. But (!) you should be wary of SQL injection if you're going that route.

Comment: True that. will use this way henceforth. Thanks.